# My data does not share the first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted to build a simple NN-Model using Tensorflow, Keras and Matplotlib. When I tried to run the Code in the shell it gave me this output

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 60000
  y sizes: 10000
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Here's how I defined the values:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist #28x28 hand written images 0-9

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
```

If you'd like to see the whole Code here's a Link to my Colab Notebook:
[Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KjLNTSBuQ_Ex2O8yIilAVjUs5b2JpnKO?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

```
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
```

should be

```
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1) 
                                    ^
```